# How to show Grand Total column using With RollUp

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

This is my code:

```
declare @sql as varchar(max)
set @sql = 'insert into #TempReport select [Country],' + @cols + '
    from
    (
        select 
            C.Country_Name AS [Country],
            D.GSL_Name AS [GSL],
            SUM(A.Allocation) AS Total
            from Work_Information A
            inner join Sales B
            on A.Sales_ID = B.Sales_Id
            inner join Countries C
            on A.Country_ID = C.Country_ID
            inner join tbl_GSL D
            on A.GSL_ID = D.GSL_ID AND A.Sales_ID = D.Sales_Id
            where A.Sales_Id = 1
            group by A.Country_ID,C.Country_Name, A.Sales_ID, A.GSL_ID,D.GSL_Name
    ) P Pivot (sum(Total) for [GSL] in (' + @Cols + ')) as Pvt'

exec(@sql)

declare @SumCols as varchar(max)
select @SumCols = stuff(
    (select ', Sum(' + quotename(GSLName) + ')' + REPLACE(GSLName,' ','')  from 
        (
            select TOP 200 GSL_Name as GSLName 
            from tbl_GSL GSL
            where Sales_Id = 1
            ORDER BY GSL_Name
        ) GlobalSales 
        ORDER BY GSLName FOR XML PATH('')
    ),1,2,'')

declare @sql3 as varchar(1000)
set @sql3 = 'select Country,' + @SumCols + ' from #TempReport group by Country WITH ROLLUP'
exec(@sql3)
```

I have posted only the relevant part of the code because the stored procedure is very long.

The code is working fine. I am using WITH ROLLUP clause to add Grand Total row and columns in the last. The last line of the code does adds a row at the last but I also want to add last column as Grand Total. Also, the last row added by ROLLUP should have first column value as Grand Total.